# Регулярные выражения: обработчик не видит %20

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Мне необходимо правильно записать регулярное выражение для адреса `www.site.ru/search/отделка%20коттеджа/`

вот что я написал:

```
'/^search\/отделка%20коттеджа\/$/i'
```

В `instanCMS` есть файл `custom_rewrite.php` он отвечает как видно из названия за перенаправления по регулярным выражениям пример:

```
$rules[] = array(
    'source'  => '/^search\/отделка%20коттеджа\/$/i',
    'target'  => '/old/other/otdelka-kottedzha.html',
    'action'  => 'redirect-301'
);
```

если бы не `%20`, то всё бы работало, но у меня страница не перенаправляется. Как обойти данную проблему не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скорее всего CMS делает urlencode для адреса и поэтому обрабатывает не `%20` а пробел, Вам нужно выражение  

    /^search\/отделка коттеджа\/$/i

Comment: Если угадал- напишите и я сделаю коммент ответом.

Comment: к сожалению не угадали, я и так тоже пробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

всё оказалось очень просто, когда я вставил эту ссылку в браузер Opera, то получил конвертацию вида:

> http://site.loc/search/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0

применив к ссылке маску регулярного выражения получил:

```
   $rules[] = array(
                         'source'  => '/^search\/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0$/i',
                       'target'  => '/old/other/otdelka-kottedzha.html',
                        'action'  => 'redirect-301'
                    );
```

всё работает, всем спасибо.

Comment: Было бы политкорректнее делать сначала urlencode пришедших в запросе данных, а потом обрабатывать выражением:  

    /^search\/отделка коттеджа\/$/i
В таком случае будет происходить редирект независимо от регистра букв в запросе.  
В Вашем решении регистр букв играет роль.